# Создание двух записей и создание связи в рамках одной транзакции(SQL)

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Всем доброго времени суток. Начал более глубоко изучать язык SQL и реляционные базы данных, без использования различных ORM.
И перед мной стал вопрос, можно ли в пределах одной транзакции создать две записи в разных таблицах, и связать их в третьей таблице (многие ко многим).

Вот пример 3-х простых таблиц:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS author(
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT null
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books(
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT null
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS author_book(
  id BIGSERIAL NOT null UNIQUE,
  author_id INTEGER NOT null,
  books_id INTEGER NOT null,
  FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES author (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (books_id) REFERENCES books (id)
);
```

А теперь я хочу выполнить транзакцию, в которой создам запись `author` и запись `books`, а вот как мне в этой же транзакции связать таблицы в таблице `author_book`:

```
BEGIN;

INSERT
  INTO author(name)
  VALUES('Alexandr');

INSERT
  INTO books(title)
  VALUES('War and world');

COMMIT;
```

В том случае, если бы айдишник в `author` и `books` я ложил из вне, я бы мог создать запись `author_book` с этими айдишниками, но в моем примере айдишники генерируются...
Как возможно это сделать?
В качестве СУБД используется Postgresql.

Comment: Я уже отвечал на такой вопрос, посмотри тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194055/posgresql-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e/1194065#1194065

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [PosgreSQL вставка в две таблицы за одну транзакцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194055/posgresql-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 2):

[Returning Data from Modified Rows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-returning.html)

```
WITH
author_insert as (
  INSERT INTO author(name)
  VALUES('Alexandr')
  RETURNING id
),
book_insert as (
  INSERT INTO books(title)
  VALUES('War and world')
  RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO author_book (author_id, books_id)
VALUES (
  (SELECT id FROM author_insert),
  (SELECT id FROM book_insert)
);
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/7584)

Comment: Спасибо большое, ответ исчерпывающий

Answer (score 1):

```sql
INSERT INTO author_book (author_id, books_id)
SELECT author.id, books.id
FROM author
CROSS JOIN books
WHERE author.name = 'Alexandr'
  AND books.title = 'War and world';
```

Comment: лишнее чтение на ровном месте и хорошо если имена уникальные